# MongoDB multiple groups in one aggregation

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, aggregation

I have the following data

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId(),
        level: 'High',
        country: 'Palestine'
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId(),
        level: 'Low',
        country: 'Jordan'
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId(),
        level: 'High',
        country: 'Jordan'
    }
]
```

I can easily group the data using the following aggregation

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$level',
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}
```

which gives the following data

```
[
    {
        _id: 'High',
        count: 2
    },
    {
        _id: 'Low',
        count: 1
    }
]
```

But I need to do that to the country as well and many other fields
is there a way to perform this in one aggregation, or should I just do the group for each aggregation alone?

For more details I wanna perform the elastic aggregation operation in mongodb

Comment: Can you clarify what output you want given the sample into (perhaps adding more docs if needed)? You can group on multiple fields by expressing them as an embedded object for the `_id` field in the `$group` specification, but it's not obvious to me if that's the output that you want or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an exact use case of `$facet` to me.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "groupByLevel": [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$level",
            count: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "groupByCountry": [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$country",
            count: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TrEk_80ptAI)